# how to add contents into a text file having various paths using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch scripting and I was trying out new stuff.

I have a file `sample.txt`. It has various paths which looks like this:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\New Text Document1.txt
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\New Text Document2.txt
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\New Text Document3.txt
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\New Text Document4.txt
```

I want to add text in this path before the file name.

I want the file to look like this:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\Backup Folder\New Text Document1.txt
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\Backup Folder\New Text Document2.txt
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\Backup Folder\New Text Document3.txt
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Sample\Backup Folder\New Text Document4.txt
```

Comment: You will use a `FOR` command and use the command modifiers to split apart the file path from the file name.  You can read about it by opening up a cmd prompt and typing: `FOR /?`.  Read the last section about the modifiers.

Comment: I think it might look something like this - 
FOR /F "delims=/" %%A IN (Sample.txt) Do (@echo + "BackUp Folder/" + *.txt) but it needs something more

Comment: No.  Do not use the `DELIMS` option.  Use the modifiers. `%~dpA` and `%~nxA`.  The delims option should be empty. `FOR /F "DELIMS="`

Comment: I am not sure how to use it but I searched on net and it shows we have to set a variable and so it might look like - FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN (Sample.txt) Do (set newtext = %~nxA)

Comment: Almost positive you did not see an example of using the `SET` command like this: `set newtext = %~nxA`.  The help for the `SET` command shows **NO** spaces in the syntax documentation.  You do not need to `SET` the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable.  Just echo out the two `FOR` variables I told you to use and it should be blatantly obvious what it does.

Comment: So something like this @(FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN (Sample.txt) Do (@Echo %~dpA "/Backup Folder"/ %~dpA"))>sample.txt

Comment: Why ask.  Just execute it and see what the output is.

Comment: I tried using that. I learnt though how to use it and the meaning.
Thanks but can you tell what is %~dpA & %~nxA

Comment: If you read the HELP for the `FOR` command it literally tells you what they do!

Comment: okay thanks a lot!!

Comment: You need to accept the answer that npocmaka gave you in your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off


set "file=sample.txt"
set "add_=Backup Folder\"

break>temp
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%file%") do (
    echo %%~dp#%add_%%%~nx#
)>>temp

move /y temp "%file%"
```

Comment: Why confuse them anymore then they are by using the # as the FOR variable. You and I know it can be done but someone who is new could read the help for the command and it literally says "letter" for the variable.

Comment: @Squashman  - I'm to used to it and sometimes I'm using it without thinking   for the newbies in the batch scripting.